# Index out of range for function to convert large number to number with suffix (million, billion....)

Tags: swift, xcode, numbers

I am a new programmer building my first incremental game for iOS. I wrote a small function to convert my large number to smaller number with suffix.

```
func numberConverter(_ number: Double) -> String {

    let intermediate = floor(log10(number)/3)
    let numberSuffix: [String] = ["K", "M", "B", "T", "Qa", "Qi", "Sx", "Sp", "Oc", "No", "Dc", "UDc", "DDc", "TDc", "QaDc"]
    let convertedNumber: String = "\(round(number / pow(10.0, intermediate * 3.0) * 1000) / 1000) \(numberSuffix[Int(intermediate) - 1])"

    return convertedNumber
}
```

When I do the conversion, I always get the "Index out of range" error.

I already tried many different searches for this, but until now no answer.

Can anyone have a look? Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Log each part. Especially the `Int(intermediate) - 1`, and the bounds of the array?

Comment: For starters - what is the logarithm of negative numbers? What is the logarithm of zero? `floor(log10(number)/3)` of all numbers < 10 is `0`. Therefore `Int(intermediate) - 1]` will become `-1`.

Comment: print the values of `intermediate`  to see where you are going wrong

Comment: Problem solved and lesson learned. Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to solve the edge cases:

```
func numberConverter(_ number: Double) -> String {
    let numIntegerDigits: Int

    // for smaller numbers than the log10 won't really make sense
    // adding the abs(...) fixes handling of negative values
    if abs(number) < 1 {
        numIntegerDigits = 0
    } else {
        numIntegerDigits = Int(floor(log10(abs(number))))
    }

    let unitIndex = numIntegerDigits / 3
    let numberSuffixes: [String] = ["K", "M", "B", "T", "Qa", "Qi", "Sx", "Sp", "Oc", "No", "Dc", "UDc", "DDc", "TDc", "QaDc"]

    // you have to solve the case when there is no unit (all values < 1000)
    guard unitIndex > 0 else {
        return String(number)
    }

    let scaledNumber = round(number / pow(10.0, Double(numIntegerDigits)) * 1000) / 1000
    let unitSuffix = numberSuffixes[unitIndex - 1]

    return "\(scaledNumber) \(unitSuffix)"
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Really appreciate your help.